# Iterating and printing std::map using std::for_each

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, stdbind

Recently, i learnt about the STL types and templates and we were given a challenge as part of practicing the STL and getting used to using it:

1. Iterate over a `std::map<std::string, size_t>`
2. Print its contents

Restrictions:

1. Can only use: `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::string`, `std::algorithm`, `std::functional`
2. Cannot define complex types nor templates
3. Cannot use the `. (member access), -> (member access via pointer), * (dereference) operators`
4. Cannot use `for, while, do-while nor if-else, switch` and other conditionals
5. Can use `std::for_each` and other functions of function templates to iterate over collection of elements
6. No lambdas
7. No `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::ostream` etc.
8. No auto types
9. Can use other STL templates so long as they are included in the headers described at (1)

Allowed to use these functions:

```
void print(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

```
std::string split(const std::pair<std::string, size_t> &r)
{
    std::string name;
    std::tie(name, std::ignore) = r;
    return name;
}
```

Originally, i had wanted to use `std::for_each(std::begin(mymap), std::end(mymap), print)` to iterate over the map and then use the print function to print out the contents. Then i realised that i am actually working with `std::pair<std::string, size_t>` which made me consider the use of `std::bind` and `std::tie` to break the `std::pair` up. But since i THINK i need to do it inside the `std::for_each` expression, how can i break up the `std::pair` while also call print on the elements?

I have also considered using `Structured Binding` but i am not allowed to use `auto`.

So, the question is, how do i make use of the STL to iterate the map to extract then print out the keys using the helper functions provided? Obviously, without the restrictions the challenge would have been very easy, but i am at a loss as to what kind of functions in the STL are appropriate in light of this.

Comment: most of these restrictions seem kind of random.

Comment: also I think you mean "The Standard Library" instead of STL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library

Comment: `std::for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),std::bind(print,std::bind(split,std::placeholders::_1)));` this line prints all keys, where `m` is your map. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YrTHXB). Because `std::bind` comes from `functional`, this code satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @rafix07 Thank you. This solution is elegant and has helped me appreciate std::bind a lot

Answer (score 0):

I used  from your function that takes a  "std::pair& as for_each third argument.

I use printf() for print values.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


std::string Split(const std::pair<std::string, size_t> &r)
{
    std::string name;
    std::tie(name, std::ignore) = r;
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    string name1{ "John" };
    string name2{ "Jack" };

    std::map<std::string, size_t> sample = { {name1, 31}, {name2, 35} };
    static vector<std::string> names;

    std::for_each(sample.begin(), sample.end(), [](std::pair<std::string, size_t> pickup)
    {
        static int i = 0;
        names.push_back(Split(pickup));
        printf("%s\n", names[i].c_str());
        i++;
    });

}
```

Comment: Now try Edited version.